# How to overcome the aspect ratio warnings when plotting images in log-scaled axis with Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, aspect-ratio, logarithm

While doing plots with scatter + images using matplotlib, I come across this kind of warnings:

```
UserWarning: aspect is not supported for Axes with xscale=log, yscale=linear
```

An example where this warning comes up is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
fig.set_size_inches(10, 10)

Image_Earth = plt.imread('Earth.png')
ax.imshow(Image_Earth, extent=[0.96,  1.04, 0.98, 1.02])

plt.xscale('log')
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
plt.show()
```

Any idea how to overcome it? Is it safe to always ignore?

Comment: Maybe `ax.imshow(...., aspect='auto')`?

Comment: It worked! Well, thank you !!